# From $P=NP$ to $NP=NL$

Tags: complexity-theory, complexity-classes

Does $P=NP$ implies $3SAT$ reduces to $2SAT$?

If so then from $2SAT$ is $NL$-complete can we conclude $NP=NL$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no.

If P=NP, then every problem in NP, in particular 3SAT, can be solved in polynomial time. Hence it reduces to every nontrivial problem (and 2SAT is nontrivial) using polynomial time reductions. Which are the reductions in the definition of NP-hardness.

NL, on the other hand, is not closed under polynomial time reductions (unless NL=P), as these can use polynomial space (exceeding logarithmic space). That is why for the definition of NL-hardness, logspace reductions are used. Hence neither can we conclude that 3SAT is in NL, nor that NL=NP.

Comment: what exactly is a logspace reduction? Note to represent $2SAT$ itself you need polynomial space and so it seems any reduction should not be in logspace.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-space_reduction. In logspace (reductions or classes), neither input nor output are included in the space bound.

Answer (score 0):

Such implication is currently unknown.

One immediate consequence of $\mathsf{P=NP\Rightarrow NL=NP}$ is that $\mathsf{P\neq PSPACE}$ unconditionally, since otherwise you have $\mathsf{NL=P=NP=PSPACE}$, contradicting the space hierarchy theorem. Note that in order to conclude $\mathsf{NP=NL}$ from a reduction between 3SAT and 2SAT, the reduction has to be limited to logarithmic space.